# Cannot find -llibmysqld Collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, windows, qt

When i was running qt application, it gives these issues. Compile output   [screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYsea.jpg). I'm using Qt\5.15.0, mingw81_32, MySQL Connector C 6.1.  Anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because of my previous server. Check answer here [Check answer here.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/115326/cannot-find-llibmysqld-collect2-exe-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status/9)